# Installing pygame or Tkinter for QGIS Python?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, windows, tkinter, importerror

I have downloaded [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) and installed it. Now i want to write scripts and run them through the QGIS console that implement methods of pygame but when the console reads "import pygame" i get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/stelios/Desktop/project/x.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Any ideas?

I suppose i have to set something like a path through QGIS options but i dont know exactly.

Comment: If you're using Windows, you might check if the PYTHONPATH system variable includes the folder where pygame stored.

Comment: How have you have installed Pygame and where ?

Comment: @gene I downloaded and run the pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi 3.1MB found in the link on my original post. Then i found the pygame folder inside C:/Python27/include and inside C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages

Comment: The problem is that is not the Python version used by QGIS (look at [QGIS Standalone and the Python Modules](http://quantumofgis.blogspot.be/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html))

Comment: @raykendo Got another question, the only place i can find PYTHONPATH is at QGIS options and it shows it in BOLD. If i check the environment variables on Windows then its not there. Is this normal?

Comment: @Stelios It's probably in the user variables list for your username above the system variables in your system's environmental variables.

Comment: @raykendo NNNNNope! I can print screen if you dont believe me!

Comment: I believe you. Go ahead and add it as a custom variable, and include the paths for your python files, including the one for pygame.